# How to stop push notifications to Garmin Vivoactive 3 from Android Phone when lost connection?

Tags: notifications, smartwatch

I have a Vivoactive 3 Series watch which is hooked up to my Android phone. When I get text messages I get notifications on my watch (what I want). However when I go in a dead zone in my house my phone will tell me that I lost data connection and then these messages get pushed to my watch.

Howe can I stop them from being pushed to my watch (I am also fine with just not seeing this message on the phone as well).